# Getting HTTP 400 when trying to upload image from Javascript to Django

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

I am trying to upload an image from HTML/JS front end to Django. Getting the following error -

```
The number of GET/POST parameters exceeded settings.DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS.
```

It's a `400 (Bad Request)` that I am getting back to the front end.

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" id="imgForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <h3> <span class="label label-default">Upload Image</span> </h3>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                        Browse… <input type="file" id="imgInp" accept="image/*" image="image" name="imgInp" />
                    </span>
                </span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
            </div>
            <img id='img-upload'/>
            <br><br>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" style="" id="tf_predict">Predict</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**JS**

```
$("#tf_predict").click(function (e){
            e.preventDefault();
            image_file = $('#imgInp')[0].files[0];//prop('files');
            //csrfmiddlewaretoken = document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value

            var myFormData = new FormData();
            myFormData.append('image_file', image_file);
            //myFormData.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', csrfmiddlewaretoken);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'http://localhost:8000/ap/predict',  // or just url: "/my-url/path/"
                processData: false,
                data: myFormData,
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data)
                    resp = JSON.parse(data);
                    perc_prob = resp.water * 100;
                    value = perc_prob.toString()+'%'
                    $('#progress_bar').text(value); 
                    $('#progress_bar').attr("style","width:"+value); 
                },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("Please report this error: "+errorThrown+xhr.status+xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
```

**Views.py**

```
def predict(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        image_data = request.FILES['image_file']
        results = {' {"water": 0.8, "nowater":0.2 } '}
        print(results)
        return HttpResponse(results)
```

My form only has the one image input that I am trying to send. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: check in your network tab to see what's actually being submitted to the server. Is it what you expected? Also, what is the value of `settings.DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS` in your config?

Comment: @ADyson I haven't set any value. Checked the docs - the default was 1000. Yes I checked the network tab... only calling the `POST` URL I wanted it to call. Let me know if you need more details

Comment: "only calling the POST URL I wanted it to call"...what was in the request body and the querystring? Exactly what you expected? I'm only thinking, somehow it could be sending extra data for some reason. Worth double-checking. Also how big is the image file?

Comment: @ADyson - The image file is `313KB`. `data: myFormData` is the form data that I am sending from Javascript (check it in the JS module). Nothing in the querystring too. I am expecting a hardcoded json response for now from views.py. I just want views.py to read the image. I will do the further processing once this roadblock is cleared

Comment: It's pretty strange then. Apparently you can run python manage.py diffsettings to check any settings which have changed from the default. Might be worth doing that, if you haven't already, to double-check there's nothing overriding the DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS

Answer (score 0):

I have just encountered similar issue. But in my case, I was trying to post multipart/form-data using requests module. My code looks like:

```
url = 'http://your.site.com/api'
the_file_data = {
   'my_image': (myimage_file.name, myimage_file.read()),
   }
form_dict = {'first_name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Doe'}
response = requests.post(url, files=the_file_data, data=form_dict, auth=(username, password))
```

Uploading small sized images does not give any problems, but files with size 2MB gives errors:

```
'The number of GET/POST parameters exceeded settings.DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS.'
```

In my case, I added parameter DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS in settings.py and set the value to 20000 (twenty thousand). It works for me. FYI, the default value is 1000 (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/).